# Getting Times of Squid3 operations

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid

We have has some complaints from outlying offices about internet access being 'slow'. I can’t really see anything wrong, but I would like to gather some data to try and find out what is going on. Ideally I would like to get some timing from a user’s session, and break it down by authentication time, time to resolve the site, time to actually get the page, time to check the whitelists etc.

Has anyone any idea the best way to go about gathering this information. We are running squid3 on an Ubuntu 12.04.1 machine, with users authenticating through our active directory.

Cheers
Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a look into /var/log/access.log ?

Read here for information about the used timestamps in the access.log file:
http://www.linofee.org/~jel/proxy/Squid/accesslog.shtml